# Saving AutoMapper mapped Collections of Entities using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, automapper

I have the following Entity Framework Entities:

```
public class Region
{
    public int RegionId { get; set; } // Primary Key
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Country> Countries { get; set; } // Link Table
}
public class Country
{
    public int CountryId { get; set; } // Primary Key
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int RegionId { get; set; } // Foreign Key
}
```

I map these using AutoMapper to the following ViewModels:

```
public class RegionViewModel
{
    public int RegionId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<int> Countries { get; set; }
}
public class CountryViewModel
{
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I want to translate my ViewModels to Entities using AutoMapper so I can save a new Region. This is my mapping code:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<RegionViewModel, Region>()
    .ForMember(x => x.Countries, x => x.MapFrom(y => y.Countries.Select(z => new Country() { CountryId = z }).ToArray()));
```

This causes an exception when adding the region in the repository as it also tries to create a new instance of Country with a null Name. One solution is to change the `Add` method in my repository to set the State of the country objects to Unchanged.

```
public async Task Add(Region region)
{
    foreach (Country country in region.Countries)
    {
        this.Context.Entry(country).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
    }
    await base.Add(region);
}
```

The other alternative solution is to use more complicated translation logic which uses another repository to get the real country objects. This approach has slower performance because it has to make an extra call to the database but you also get a more complete Region object.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<RegionViewModel, Region>();
Mapper.CreateMap<int[], Country[]>().ConvertUsing(x => countryRepository.GetAll().Result.Where(y => x.Contains(y.CountryId)).ToArray());
```

I lean to the first one but what is the correct approach?

Comment: Why do you need to use automapper? Could you use entity as your viewmodel?

Comment: I use AutoMapper to save time writing boilerplate translation code. Every if you remove AutoMapper from the question. I think the question still stands. What is the correct approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first method, together with the loop to set the states to `UnChanged`, is definitely the best one. It is lightweight, because you don't needlessly fetch `Country`s from the database. Instead, by the mapper part...

```
y.Countries.Select(z => new Country() { CountryId = z })
```

...you create *stub entities*, i.e. incomplete entities that serve as a placeholders for the real things. That's a commonly [recommended approach to reduce network traffic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/06/19/tip-26-how-to-avoid-database-queries-using-stub-entities.aspx).

Setting the states to `UnChanged` is one of several ways to attach the stub `Country`s to the context. You have to attach them before calling `base.Add(region)` (which I assume adds the region to the `Regions` of the context), because `Add` marks all entities in an object graph off the added entity as new (`Added`) when they're not yet attached to the context.

Comment: Another answer by Gert also helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26518508/two-different-objects-with-same-key-for-entity-framework-does-not-work

Comment: `{ CountryId = z }` how do you convert an entity to int here??

Comment: @AkmalSalikhov `y.Countries` is a list of integers.

Comment: This is the first time I have read about EF stub entities. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think attaching a graph of entities to the DbContext is not the correct approach, because it forces you to write a lot of code to fix entity states to prevent EF from duplicating your entities.

A safer and simpler approach IMO is to load your Region entity from the DbContext, then add/remove Country entities from the Countries collection, then call SaveChanges.

You can write a generic collection mapping method, something like (not tested):

```
static class EfUtils
{
    public static void SyncCollections<TEntity>(
        ICollection<TEntity> collectionFromDb,
        IEnumerable<TEntity> collectionFromVm,
        IEqualityComparer<TEntity> equalityComparer,
        Action<TEntity, TEntity> syncAction)
        where TEntity : class, new()
    {
        var dbToVmEntitiesMap = new Dictionary<TEntity, TEntity>();
        var newEntities = new List<TEntity>();

        foreach (var vmEntity in collectionFromVm)
        {
            var dbEntity = collectionFromDb.FirstOrDefault(x => equalityComparer.Equals(x, vmEntity));
            if (dbEntity == null)
            {
                dbEntity = new TEntity();
                newEntities.Add(dbEntity);
            }

            dbToVmEntitiesMap.Add(dbEntity, vmEntity);
        }

        var removedEntities = collectionFromDb.Where(x => !dbToVmEntitiesMap.ContainsKey(x)).ToList();

        foreach (var addedOrUpdatedEntityPair in dbToVmEntitiesMap)
        {
            syncAction(addedOrUpdatedEntityPair.Key, addedOrUpdatedEntityPair.Value);
        }

        foreach (var removedEntity in removedEntities)
        {
            collectionFromDb.Remove(removedEntity);
        }

        foreach (var newEntity in newEntities)
        {
            collectionFromDb.Add(newEntity);
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I assumed the Countries collection contained editable Country view-models.
But actually it contains the IDs of the countries.
In that case you would need to apply the same add/remove pattern:

```
var regionFromDb = dbContext.Set<Region>().Find(regionVm.RegionId);
var countriesToRemove = regionFromDb.Countries.Where(x => !regionVm.Countries.Contains(x.CountryId)).ToList();
foreach (var country in countriesToRemove)
{
    regionFromDb.Countries.Remove(country);
}

var countryIdsToAdd = regionVm.Countries.Where(x => !regionFromDb.Countries.Any(c => c.CountryId == x)).ToList();

// Load countries where CountryId in countryIdsToAdd collection
var countriesToAdd = dbContext.Set<Country>().Where(x => countryIdsToAdd.Contains(x.CountryId));
foreach (var country in countriesToAdd)
{
    regionFromDb.Countries.Add(country);
}

dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: This is perhaps the approach that is safer and easier to understand. However, you have to do extra database queries.